# Is there a way to convert a video from iOS (QuickTime) format to Windows (WMV or AVI) format?

Tags: windows, ipod-touch, video, quicktime

I recently purchased an iPod 5 and had the opportunity to take videos with it. The videos are great; but, I have a problem.

I would love to be able to convert these videos from their original Quick Time format to something that my computer "prefers" playing such as WAV or AVI.

Is there a way to do this without using an online converter (which I would really prefer not doing)? I have immediate access to Windows Media Player, Movie Maker and Quick Time. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: get QuickTime for Windows http://support.apple.com/kb/dl837

Comment: @Buscar웃 I do have that already; I would just like to convert them.

Comment: [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/downloads.php)

Comment: Why this negative vibe? That's no good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For all conversion tasks, I like to recommend [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/). There are versions for MacOS, Windows and Linux, and its use does not involve messing around with command lines.

Answer (score 5):

Videos recorded with iOS (your iPod 5) have the extension "MOV", but they are normal "MP4" (containing H.264 and AAC). Which means that you can change the extension to "MP4" and they will be playable on Windows.

In this case (recorded on iOS and with the extension "MOV") it is not necessary to convert these files. Same for "M4V" and "M4H" (other extensions which are used sometimes by Apple products on iOS).

There are two ways to change the extension of a file for Mac users:

1. Directly in the Finder

   - Select the file
   - Hit ENTER to edit the filename
   - Select the extension "MOV" (without ".")
   - Change the extension to "mp4"
   - Hit ENTER to exit editing
2. In the Finder information window

   - Select the file
   - Select "Information" in the File menu (or press CMD + I)
   - Select the extension "MOV" (without ".") in the field "Name & Suffix"
   - Change the extension to "mp4"
   - Close the information window

Both ways will show a dialog to confirm the changed extension.

For Windows users, please read the [help from Microsoft](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/file-names-extensions-faq#1TC=windows-7).

Uppercase or lowercase of the extension is the same, but I prefer lowercase.

Comment: Good answer but, If you could add some recommended converters. Someone gave you a -1 for not providing that information.

Comment: @Buscar웃 I assume the downvote was due to incorrect information rather than not providing software references. Either way, whomever down voted should have provided a reason. [Clarification is required regarding containers vs. codecs](http://www.dr-lex.be/info-stuff/mediaformats.html). `.mov` files natively support `.mp4` codecs (i.e., `H.264`), while `.avi` files don't. This is why you can simply change the extension on a `.mov` file to `.mp4` without issue - changing the extension from `.mov` to `.avi`, on the other hand, wouldn't work. Conversion *is necessary* in this case.

Comment: @njboot If you want to join the "downvote with/without comment" discussion you can do so [here](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1693/downvoting-etiquette-with-or-without-making-a-comment).

Comment: @ R. Rudolph I would appreciate knowing _how_ to do this. If you can explain that to me than I will mark yours as answered.

Comment: @ L.B. I added a description how to do this. Let me know if it needs improvements.

Comment: So basically you are saving that it a .MOV video can be played by any AVI-capable player after renaming video.MOV to video.AVI?

Comment: @patrix No - I said that videos recorded with iOS and the extension "MOV" can be changed to the extension "mp4" because they are MP4 movies. Other "MOV" files can contains other formats and changing the extension might not help.

Comment: It might help to make this more obvious in your answer then and remove the reference to AVI

Comment: @patrix L.B. mentioned WAV and AVI, and I thought it would be nice to reference these by giving a short comment (instead of ignoring it). But I removed it now and hope it is more helpful now. Thanx for the improvement ideas.

Comment: @R.Rudolph It is very easy to understand now, thanks! However, I'm not quite sure I fully understand what the "finder" is. Is that something that is present on Windows XP?

Comment: @L.B. Sorry - the description for changing the extension is for Mac users. I added a link with a description for Win users as well. Thanx for this hint and sorry for my "blindness".

Comment: @R.Rudolph It's okay:)

Comment: @L.B. May be you should change the question to "How to convert videos recorded on iOS to watch them on Windows" or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert those MOV Videos and other by a lot of Video Converters Out there in the Internet. E.g. VLC, Miro, and many more http://www.lmgtfy.com/?q=mov%20to%20wmv

But keep in mind converting to WAV gives you an Audio File.

I recommend you to convert in either WMV (Windows Media Video) AVI (Audio Video Interleave).

But it can be even simpler if you just wana  play those Movies on your PC just install VLC (VideoLAN Client) this Opensource Media Player can play almost any Video and Audio Filetype.

You can get it here: http://www.videolan.org/vlc/

Comment: Sending people to Google usually doesn't help, it improves answer quality if you propose specific tools (ideally those you have experience with).

Comment: but if i get the conclusion that one was to lazy to google it or maybe has tried with the wrong search words ;-)

Comment: Anyone can google, but selecting the good results among all the crap searching for "mov to wmv" returns isn't that easy.